# Is this the proper way of switching the "Edit My Profile" link with my BuddyPress "Extended Profile" link?

Tags: filters

I am using the Multisite feature enabled. I have a main site and a community site. On the main site the 'Edit My Profile' links is pointing to this link:

```
http://www.mysitename.com/community/wp-admin/profile.php
```

But when I am visiting my community site the 'Edit my Profile' link points to this link:

```
http://www.mysitename.com/community/members/username/profile/edit/
```

I want the link on the main site to show the exact link as my Community site is showing which is an extended BuddyPress profile.  So, I went ahead and added this filter to my main site's functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'edit_profile_url', 'my_modified_profile_url', 10, 3 );

function my_modified_profile_url( $url, $user_id, $scheme )
{
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $url = site_url( '/community/members/' . $current_user->user_login . '/profile/edit/' );
    return $url;
}
```

This returns the exact URL that I want and it includes the username in the URL which is perfect. Is this the proper way of doing it?

I used $user_id in this line:

```
$url = site_url( '/community/members/' . $user_id . '/profile/edit/' );
```

But that returned the user ID number and the link was broken.

Comment: I used the same filter but with `->user_nicename` or another user link wrongly (does `site_url()` already `esc_url()` or must be added somewhere?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I've done:

```
<?php 
    $link = home_url( '/members/' . bp_core_get_username( bp_displayed_user_id() ) . '/followers/' );
    echo "<a href='". esc_attr( $link ) ."'>Followers</a>";
?>
```

So maybe its `home_url` now, than site_url. In the echo, `esc_attr` gives out the $link.

Change the whole `bp_core_get_username( bp_displayed_user_id() )` to whatever you need - `wp_get_current_user()` for example.